# What is DAB modulation in signal generators?

Tags: signal-analysis, modulation, radio

I am using R&S signal generator and for generating a DAB signal there is an option for mentioning the modulation level in %. For example, we can generate DAB modulation 50% . I can understand that for AM radios, we mention modulation in %. What does this modulation in % mean for DAB or T-DMB ?

Comment: Nothing. I've advised a student implementing a DAB+ transceiver (he was extremely independent and reliable, not much advising to be done), and that appears nowhere. Makes no sense, either – DAB is an OFDM system with –curiously– differential QPSK on the subcarriers. Nothing that can have a modulation depth. R&S has probably just "abused" an existing GUI element, or it doesn't do anything for DAB – read the documentation that came with that expensive device. (and afterwards, enjoy the free https://github.com/kit-cel/gr-dab)